# Android SurfaceView NullPointerException after FragmentTransaction

Tags: android, multithreading, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, surfaceview

What the code is doing:
Masks a rectangular bitmap image using a circular bitmap mask. This code works if in a layout on it's own, but fails if it's the incomming view in a fragment replace transaction.

```
@Override
public void run() {


    while(isRunnable){
        // draw to the canvas
        //if the surface isn't available go back to the top of the loop
        if(!surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()){
            continue;
        }

        result = Bitmap.createBitmap(maskImage.getWidth(), maskImage.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        //lock the canvas before trying to draw to it
        canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
        maskPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        maskPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));

        //null pointer exception at this line
        tempCanvas = new Canvas(result);
        //draw the bitmaps to the canvas
        canvas.drawARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);


        tempCanvas.drawBitmap(userIconImage, imageX - userIconImage.getWidth()/2,
                imageY - userIconImage.getHeight()/2, null);
        tempCanvas.drawBitmap(maskImage, maskX, maskY, maskPaint);
        maskPaint.setXfermode(null);
        //draw in the centre of the canvas
        canvas.drawBitmap(result, this.getWidth()/2 - maskImage.getWidth()/2,
                this.getHeight()/2 - maskImage.getHeight()/2, new Paint());

        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

    }
    result = null;

}// run()
```

The Problem:
I have two fragements which are being swapped using a `FragmentTransaction`. The second fragment is inflating a custom view which is a `SurfaceView`.
The view begins to get drawn, but after a seemlingly arbitrary number of iterations of the while loop I get a `NullPointerException.`
For example the last 10 runs loop counts are 46,6,5,12,10,51,25,115,43,9. The only other evidence I can gather is that when I step through the code I see 'paused in another thread'.

This is the exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1250
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.graphics.Canvas.<init>(Canvas.java:126)
at my.name.test.controller.CustomSurfaceView.run(CustomSurfaceView.java:109)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
```

Comment: Is `result` null at the point of the exception?

Comment: Yeah, I thought the same thing. But no, it never is null at the point of the exception.

Comment: What version of Android are you using? You can see the source code online (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/marshmallow-mr2-release/graphics/java/android/graphics/Canvas.java), but for the line numbers to work the version needs to match (and the device needs to have an unmodified AOSP Canvas.java, but one step at a time).

Comment: Turns out you were correct. I was checking for null right before it. But it does sometimes become null when it hits `tempCanvas = new Canvas(result)`. Code in the post has been amended.